# Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 C++ Code Assistance Issues Map with Vector Value Declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans

I am trying to set up a variable of type `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> arrayInfo84` in NetBeans, but this is causing Code Assistance to throw a fit saying

> Unable to resolve Identifier arrayInfo84
>
> Unexpected token: map
>
> Unexpected token: ;

My other map variables with more basic datatypes (i.e. `string` `int` etc.) work fine. It seems to be an issue with vectors. And before anyone asks, yes I do have `#include<vector>` in my header.

I'm guessing this is some issue with supporting C++11. However, I cannot figure out how to fix this. My tool collection is the latest version of CygWin.

Comment: Try using `> >` instead of `>>` in the template definition (assuming you also `#include <map>`)

Comment: @vsoftco yes I included `#include <map> `, and sorry template definition? I'm afraid I'm not familiar. Where can I find that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant here: `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> arrayInfo84`. Try putting a space between the last `>>`, like `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > arrayInfo84`

Comment: @vsoftco wow that solved it. What is the explanation behind this? If you could please submit an answer containing your solution and the reason why that edit works and I'll edit my post hopefully this will help solve future problems for people

Comment: Will write an answer in detail just now

Comment: @99ProblemsAndTheyreAllCode It's because your c++ compiler doesn't know what do you mean by `>>`: a nested template declaration, or just an operator `>>`, so just remember that operators have stronger priority.

Comment: Is your project configured to use c++11? (that's in project properties/C++ Compiler/C++ Standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue lies probably in the definition:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> arrayInfo84;
//                              here ^^ is the problem
```

The last token is `>>`, which in pre-C++11 (C++98/C++03) was parsed as the bit-shift operator. This was because of the fact that C++ uses the so called ["principle of maximal munch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch). Because of this fact, nested templates had always to use `> >` as their delimiter, so the above declaration should have been

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > arrayInfo84;
//    note the additional space here ^^^
```

However, C++11 relaxed the rule, and now it is allowed to have `>>` as the delimiter of a nested template, so your definition is valid in C++11, but not valid in C++98/C++03.

Your Netbeans code analyzer may not follow the latest C++11 rule, and that's why you may get the warning. Make sure you configure your compiler with support for C++11, like passing the flag `-std=c++11`, and also the code analyzer (if it's not automatically following the compiler).